# Does database modify the actual data page when we create a clustered index?

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index

I am not a dba guy, so, this might be a pretty simple question, but please help me to clarify my doubt.

We are using SQL Server 2012 in our environment.

I was reading about data pages. I came to know that, if the records in a data page need to be order, the data in the slot array (pointer of the actual data) gets re-ordered, not the actual data. I can understand this. But what if I create an clustered index in a heap table, where only rearranging the slot array is not enough, in that case, does database modify the actual data of the data page?

Let's say first row should be from page:1, second row should be from page:5 and third row should be from page:2. Does db create new page with these records and then maintain the slot array for ordering?

I hope my question is clear. If you need any further information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a short answer to this one : Yes

Comment: Oh! I was hoping there is some smarter way :) Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Updates *in-place* are possible, though not guaranteed, whenever no indexed fields of the clustered index are modified. That is to say, when only attribute fields of the clustered index are modified.